# How to make a password reset request in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, post, reset-password

I'm trying to use postman to make a post request to reset the password, to the wordpress site. Here is what query is obtained as a result: `https://example.com/wp-login.php?action=lostpassword&user_login=User123`

And in the end I get the answer: ERROR: Enter a username or email address. How to make a request correctly and is it even possible?

[image]

Comment: are you trying to sent this link in email or anything else? please explain more what you have tried? and you want to do??

Comment: @Darshkhakhkhar I want to pass a user_login or user_email to the post request. To ensure that the mail sent to the user sent an email with a password for password recovery

Comment: you just have to pass "https://example.com/wp-login.php?action=lostpassword" this portion in email and after accessing the page user have to enter email or user id to get the mail with instructions to set new password

Comment: @Darshkhakhkhar Yes, this request really tries to reset the password. The problem is that the site is waiting for a username or password to reset. So I want to know which parameter stores the username or email for post request

Comment: in that page user have to enter their username or email manually. in the box below  and it will find the user linked with that email or username and sends them a mail.. you don't have to pass  the username  by yourself

Comment: @Darshkhakhkhar Yes, the site user would have done so, but I'm developing applications for ios and I need to do everything with query tools. But you puzzled me and I solved my problem. user_login was necessary to specify not in params, and body

Comment: okay great. you didn't mention that you are doing it for ios app i thought you are implementing simple forgot password link for web.

Answer (score 5):

**I got it!**

What OP did wrong was sending the `user_login` value in `Postman's Params` instead of `form-data` or `x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Here is the working Postman request

[image: The success response contains "Check your email" as title until WordPress change that]

**But that's not all.**
I am using Flutter for developing my mobile app and `http` package to send the request and the normal `http.post()` won't work. It only works with `MultipartRequest` for some reason.

Here is the full working request for Flutter's http package.

```dart
String url = "https://www.yourdomain.com/wp-login.php?action=lostpassword";

Map<String, String> headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data; charset=UTF-8',
  'Accept': 'application/json',
};

Map<String, String> body = {
  'user_login': userLogin
};

var request = http.MultipartRequest('POST', Uri.parse(url))
  ..fields.addAll(body)
  ..headers.addAll(headers);

var response = await request.send();

// forgot password link redirect on success
if ([
  200,
  302
].contains(response.statusCode)) {
  return 'success';
} else {
  print(response.statusCode);
  throw Exception('Failed to send. Please try again later.');
}
```