# Wordpress REST API - send reset password link

Tags: c#, xamarin, wordpress-rest-api

I want to create a request from my application. (iOS and Android - Coded with Xamarin).

**Explaination:**

The request should trigger the WordPress `action=lostpassword`. - The user receives an email to reset his password in browser.

OR

The user will be able to set a new password. WordPress send a link to email - where the user has to verify, that he changed the password.
Is there any chance to do this with a request to the REST API.

Maybe any similar ideas?

I have already tried:

1. Plugins where function was given in documentation but not worked for me
2. Manualy called `wp-login.php?action=lostpassword` with body

> {
>          "redirect_to": "",
>          "user_login": "name@provider.de",
>          "wp-submit": "Neues+Passwort"
>       }

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create your custom api

**URL**

https://yourdomain/api/forgot_password.php

**Parameter**

login:manoj.infoways@gmail.com

Create folder api in root and create file forgot_password.php

forgot_password.php

```
<?php include '../wp-load.php';

$login = $_REQUEST['login']; 

if ( empty( $login ) ) {
    $json = array( 'code' => '0', 'msg' => 'Please enter login user detail' );
    echo json_encode( $json );
    exit;     
}

$userdata = get_user_by( 'email', $login); 

if ( empty( $userdata ) ) {
    $userdata = get_user_by( 'login', $login );
}

if ( empty( $userdata ) ) {
    $json = array( 'code' => '101', 'msg' => 'User not found' );
    echo json_encode( $json );
    exit;
}

$user      = new WP_User( intval( $userdata->ID ) ); 
$reset_key = get_password_reset_key( $user ); 
$wc_emails = WC()->mailer()->get_emails(); 
$wc_emails['WC_Email_Customer_Reset_Password']->trigger( $user->user_login, $reset_key );


$json = array( 'code' => '200', 'msg' => 'Password reset link has been sent to your registered email' );
echo json_encode( $json );
exit;

?>
```

login is parameter name keep in mind.

its working 100% for me try it

Comment: the $wc_emails function is for woocommerce so is there any similar function in WordPress?

Comment: This requires woocommerce. How do we do it without woocomerce?

Answer (score 2):

I think [this](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/lostpassword_url) should help you.

Example shows return a lost password URL http://example.com/lostpassword/ for the wp_lostpassword_url() function:

```
add_filter( 'lostpassword_url', 'my_lost_password_page', 10, 2 );
function my_lost_password_page( $lostpassword_url, $redirect ) {
    return home_url( '/lostpassword/?redirect_to=' . $redirect );
}
```

Comment: Oh, dont know i could call it like this. Thanks! I tried and worked for me! :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can create custom endpoint using this code inside function.php or any other place like custom plugin

```
function custom_user_forget_password($request)
{
    $email = $request->get_param('email');

    $userdata = get_user_by('email', $email);

    if (empty($userdata)) {
        $userdata = get_user_by('login', $email);
    }

    if (empty($userdata)) {
        return __('User not found');
    }

    $user = new WP_User(intval($userdata->ID));
    $reset_key = get_password_reset_key($user);
    $wc_emails = WC()->mailer()->get_emails();
    $wc_emails['WC_Email_Customer_Reset_Password']->trigger($user->user_login, $reset_key);

    return __('Password reset link has been sent to your registered email.');

}
add_action('rest_api_init', function () {
    register_rest_route('custom/v1/', '/forget_password', array(
        'methods' => 'POST',
        'callback' => 'custom_user_forget_password',
    ));
});
```

then you can call post request for this endpoint (URL /wp-json/custom/v1/forget_password) anywhere you want, and it will send a password reset link if the user exists.

Answer (score 0):

Check this answer out for a working `API call with Postman` to trigger sending password reset link in WordPress via RESTful API and working `code for Flutter`

https://stackoverflow.com/a/73467945/2218290