# Wordpress password reset from external app via ajax or rest api

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, typescript, ionic-framework

I have the same problem like this here:
[Wordpress REST API - send reset password link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52035737/wordpress-rest-api-send-reset-password-link)

I also tried it with post request to "mydomain/wplogin.php?action=lostpassword" with some parameters. But this didn`t work.

Can somebody explain me, how the wp_lostpassword_url() function works for this problem?
It is described in the first answer of the linked post, but I don`t know how to use it.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/lostpassword_url

```
add_filter( 'lostpassword_url', 'my_lost_password_page', 10, 2 );
function my_lost_password_page( $lostpassword_url, $redirect ) {
    return home_url( '/lostpassword/?redirect_to=' . $redirect );
}
```

Can somebody show me some lines of code where and how to use it?

Thanks very much.

Edit:

To make it more clear what I want to achieve. In my Ionic App I want to present a button for the user, which triggers after click a request to my wordpress page. Than the user should get a mail with the password reset link. The request should return a success or fail message. So I can present the user the fail or success message. Is this possible with the filter hook described above, or can I use a rest api route for this?

Comment: can you give more details about your question. it is not clear what you want

Comment: Thanx fur your reply. I edited the question.